# My flutter android back button event is not triggering using willpopscope

Tags: flutter, dart

Help! my will pop not even printing. Here is the code:

```
  Future<bool> _willPopCallback() async {
    print('Hi');
    return false;
  }
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _willPopCallback,
      child: Scaffold()
```

Comment: Please include [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) not only the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It was not working i tried my best so at the end i started using a package called **back_button_interceptor**. Its easy to use you can find here:

https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor/example

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).